# standard bootstrap template issues with textfield and datetimepicker

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I am using the standard MVC bootstrap template and got a few issues:

1) See the screenshot below. How can I get rid of the cross from appearing in the textfield with focus?

2) The text in the date is too left aligned unlike all the other fields. I am using the bootstrap datetimepicker here.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to create a `custom.css` class to overwrite the default `bootstrap.css`.and place a link reference of your `custom.css` below `bootstrap.css`

1. In getting rid of the cross, right click on it, navigate to inspect in your browsers context menu. Take a look at the inspector, The cross and the border color are triggered by the focus state of the Textbox. In Chrome click :hov and select :focus, this will display the css that styles the text control when it is clicked. You should find the element that styles the Cross. Simply copy the whole class into your custom.css and remove the attribute that styles the cross
2. For the Datapicker you need to rightclick on the date displayed go to inspect, copy the class into your `custom.css` and add padding-left of the desired pixels you want eg `padding-left:20px;`

Sample Inspector In Chrome

[image]